# Ubuntu Pro: Another process is running APT

Tags: apt, 22.04, lock, canonical-livepatch, ubuntu-pro

I am trying to enable **esm-apps** on my Ubuntu 22.04 machine (**pro enable esm-apps**), but it keeps on failing to update package lists 'Another process is running APT.' while 'apt update' is working perfectly without any problem with APT lock...

I tried removing **/var/lib/ubuntu-advantage/apt-esm/var/lib/apt/lists/lock** and **/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend** and **/var/lib/apt/lists/lock** and even searching for any process opened this file with **fuser -vik {LOCK_FILE}** but that didn't work too...

I kept on searching on Google for similar problem but all the content i found was errors regarding lock files (which I already tried earlier)

I tried searching on processes list for any related executables like **http**, **https**, **apt**, **apt-get**, **dpkg** but i didn't find any running executables like these

Comment: did you try rebooting the PC? Any flock should be released [Stack reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987606/is-flock-automatically-released-on-process-exit)

Comment: unfortunately i tried that two times but it didn't work

Comment: The lock we look for is the /var/lib/dpkg/lock file.
Is there a mention to apt update or apt install in the error message you see on the screen? Feel free to run $ sudo ubuntu-bug ubuntu-advantage-tools to report this as a bug so our team can take a deeper look into it.